# TFS url with server name is not working

Tags: tfs

I am facing an issue on accessing TFS portal using

```
http://ServerName:8080/tfs
```

it's showing "Page cannot be displayed"...! It's happening only in the TFS server. Portal is working fine when I access it from other machines.

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs is working perfectly in the server.
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You need to open port 8080 in windows firewall possibly although tfs installation generally does this. Or change the port number to 80 in iis manager

Comment: Port 8080 is already open in Windows firewall. Cannot change the port to 80 as it's already assigned to another site. Thank you for the comment

Comment: See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: I have tired the steps mentioned in that blog to disable Loopback check. But it's still showing "Page cannot be displayed"..!!
Could you please share, if there is any other things cases this issue?

Comment: drop in a dummy site and see if you can get to the machine at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved and the steps shown below.

1. Mapping of IP address to host name was missing in the host file. An entry has been created in the "host" file under "C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc".
2. The loopback check functionality has been disabled by creating registry key under the location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck and assigned the value “1”.
3. Restarted the machine.

Thank you very much for the replies.