# TFS 2012: URL not reachable

Tags: tfs, installation

after a servercrash we installed TFS on a new server. I used Application Tier only for 
restoring the databases, and in the Team Foundation Express Administration Console everything shows up.

When on the server I surf to the URL I get a Windows login screen and after entering credentials it proceeds to the website.

However, if I try this from an PC, the URL is not reachable.

I've checked the firewall (even disabled it for test), put port 8080 is added.

I gues something is wrong with the authentication, hence the Windows login screen, but fail to find.

Anyone ideas?

I use TFS Express 2012.4 on Server 2019

Comment: I found TFS Powertools and this revealed a service account was missing a SQL login. So I created the service account, but how to grant it SQL login?

Comment: Managed to add service account, but still no luck. Powertools report no more errors. When on server I use the localhost:8080/tfs URL it works, but when I use the http://<servername>:8080/tfs I get the windows login screen. Can't figure ouy why.

Comment: Reboot of server fixed most of the last issues, and I forgot to grant port 8080 access for private. Had only domain selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to access `http://localhost:8080/tfs`  url and work properly.

This tell you TFS is up and running. So issue should not related to IIS side.

> Try to **disable loopback** by creating registry key under the
>   location
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck`
>   and assigned the value “1”.
>
> Details follow this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_foxhole/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way/).

If you do not want to disable your firewall during daily usage. Make sure Port 8080 is open in Windows firewall.

Also take a look at this similar issue: [TFS url with server name is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194821/tfs-url-with-server-name-is-not-working)